# Popover ViewController with Table View when user Select a UITextView using Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller

Thank you for your help in advance.

Basically, I am working on an application where I want it to do the following: when the user tap on a UITextView, I want a popover ViewController to pop over the existing ViewController while the background becomes blurry. And inside the new ViewController that popped up I want a tableView to be displayed where the user can select from the list or enter a custom value of he/she wants to.

Also, is it possible to have a dropdown arrow inside the UITextView at the far right side to hint to the user that there is a drop list menu?

Bearing in mind that, I am new to coding could someone please guide me on what is the best way to achieve what I am looking for and some useful tutorials to follow?

Again thanks a lot your help on the above matter is much appreciated :-)

Regards, 
Shadi.

Comment: Shadi, your describing a picker UI element I beieve. Google UI elements in iOS and you will find an answer to this question & more perhaps. I did so and got this; https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I am not looking for UIPickerViews as I have used them before. What I am looking for is to have a UITextView and inside it to the right side there will be a little downward arrow indicating to the user that there is a drop down list if you tap the UITextView. Thus, here comes my first question: (1) How can I insert an image to a UITextView to the far right side, meanwhile, maintaining the text to the left of it?

Comment: Shadi, can you not use both. Your in charge. Put the picker control next to the uitextview. When I select an item on it... copy that to the uitextview?